# Why I can't create a cups connection in my raspberry pi using python?

Tags: python, printing, raspberry-pi

I want to use python code to print to my printer. I installed all the required module but it's not running. 
The error I got is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Thesis/print_usingcups.py", line 2, in <module>
    conn = cups.Connection()
AttributeError: module 'cups' has no attribute 'Connection'
```

I got the code from the internet here's the code

```
import cups
conn = cups.Connection()
printers = conn.getPrinters ()
for printer in printers:
print (printer, printers[printer]["device-uri"])
```

my expected output is like this
`EPSON_LX-300 usb://EPSON/LX-300+?serial=L010209081
RICOH_Aficio_SP_100 usb://RICOH/
Aficio?serial=T382M977983` but I received an error.

Comment: Please show us the full error traceback!

Comment: Hi sir, I edited the post and put the full error traceback.

Comment: Now, in the folder you run your code from, open an interactive interpreted by running just `python`, and on the `>>>` prompt run `import cups`, then `cups`! What's the output?

Comment: Hi sir, it's okay now. Thank you so much! I think i installed an outdated version of cups, it's version is 0.0.6 while the pycups is 1.9.74. I uninstalled the cups and reinstall pycups.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you wouldn't have installed cups instead of pycups?

suggestion:

```
pip uninstall cups
pip install pycups
```

and try again

Comment: I got it now sir, thanks. I installed the cups module, I thinks it's outdated or something. Instead of using pycups as a module my code used cups which is an outdated version. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Attempting to run `pip install pycups` results in the error below:

`Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-g7Dc7A/pycups/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-4JsSZe/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-g7Dc7A/pycups/`

Running `pip3 install pycups` IS successful; however I continue to get "no module named cups".  I will continue to investigate and post a solution if I find one.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30934401)